# Speak low/lowly

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

1. Speak very low.
2. Speak very lowly.

Research: Low can, according to Oxford dictionary, mean low sound, low in height, or maybe "low in importance".
Lowly, according to Oxford dictionary, mean low in social class but there are other dictionaries where they become vague.

According to some dictionaries, lowly is never an adverb. But to Oxford dictiionary:

Lowly is an adjective and adverb as well.
Are they interchangeable in certain contexts?

Comment: Both _low_ and _lowly_ can be an adjective and an adverb. I would only use _lowly_ as an adjective (of low status), but apparently it can be used as an adverb too, so, yes, they are interchangeable here.

Comment: Even when talking about low sound or low as in height?

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives this example: "Dr. Park began to speak lowly, and in Korean".

Comment: But according to some dictionaries, lowly is not an adverb either?

Comment: I've already said that I never use it as an adverb, but some dictionaries say that it can be one

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. This is potentially an interesting question. To "speak highly of someone" is a common usage, but we don't flip it around and "speak lowly of someone." Why not?

Comment: This is a tricky one. Not only the ly-form vs flat adverb issue, and the ly-form vs the standard adjective issue, and how these interrelate, but also (for other senses of 'low') the adverb vs depictive construction issue. Oh, and whether the adjective 'low' when relating to sound means 'low in volume' or 'low in pitch'. One sees why 'sotto voce' has caught on.